# How to visually simulate sending a SMS?

Tags: android, android-intent

Is there any way to populate the address and SMS body AFTER launching the intent? I'd like to first open the app responsible for sending the SMS that, like this:

```
Intent smsIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
startActivity(smsIntent);
```

And then wait a few seconds and fill the address, wait a bit more and fill the body.

Comment: You could add all the information to the Intent itself, then use a [Timer](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/java/util/Timer.html) to place the info on the user interface (I am guessing a Activity)

Comment: But I don't control the application launched by the intent. It should work on the default SMS app that comes with the device for example.

Comment: Once an Intent has been "started" you no longer control it. Like you said, the second application now expects a full Intent to do is chores. What are expecting to do here? Why cant you create a full Intent?

Comment: I was trying to create a generic tutorial for, for example, sending a SMS. My idea was to launch the default SMS app of the device along with an overlay and fill the data gradually after some hints were displayed on the overlay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you cannot interact with another process (another application) unless by specific APIs from that application. This means that `you` the developer, cannot order `an application` to do anything other than what it has allowed you to do so. (This is mostly for security, otherwise you could order a SMS application to give Contacts or other app provided info.)

If what you need is a demonstration, the I suggest making several "incremental" apps.
Start with one that "does X"... then "does x, y", then "x, y , z and etc.."

This way, the reader can tell what is the purpose of each code written.